# Prop in Partial check, but still undefined?

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript 3.7.2, but it happens also in earlier Typescript versions. strictNullChecks is On.

I have this little code piece:

```js
interface Test {
    one: boolean;
    two: boolean;
}

function getPropOrFalse(someTest: Partial<Test>, prop: keyof Test): boolean {
    if (prop in someTest) {
        const value = someTest[prop];
        return value; // <-- typescript determines this still to be boolean | undefined. Why??
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't understand, why my constant `value` is still `boolean|undefined` after that `prop in someTest` check. Anyone knows the rationale behind it?

**Edit**: Changing `prop in someTest` to `someTest[prop] !== undefined` does not change the outcome, by the way.

Comment: That's a tough one, well I can not really explain why therefore this comment. But it is based on the Partial<Test>. Removing it and the compiler is happy because the in keyword can be used a type guard then. But adding a manual type guard, doesn't solve the problem with Partial<Test>, which is weird ... here is what I sketched: https://codesandbox.io/s/qnr0d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.  First:

TypeScript does not have much allowance for the [distinction](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) between properties/function parameters that are *missing* and ones that are *present but `undefined`*.  The "optionality" annotation `foo?: Bar` represents both situations.  And, `Partial<Test>` evaluates to a type with two optional properties, equivalent to `{one?: boolean, two?: boolean}`.

Therefore I can call this:

```
getPropOrFalse({ one: undefined }, "one"); // oops
```

That's just the way the compiler is right now (until and unless [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) gets addressed in some way).  I could imagine jumping through a lot of hoops to make the call signature of `getPropOrFalse()` disallow a `someTest` parameter with present-but-`undefined` properties, but the compiler probably still wouldn't understand the implications of that inside the implementation of `getPropOrFalse()`, so you'd have to use assertions and the like.  I'd say it's healthier not to fight against the type system and allow for present-but-`undefined` properties.

The `in` operator checks for the presence of a property, but it does not check if the value of the property is `undefined` or not.  Therefore the `in` operator is insufficient to check for an optional property, while the `typeof foo.prop === "undefined"` actually checks if the property is `undefined` or not.  (Yes, I know, not in your case; read on!)  This difference can be demonstrated with the following:

```
function getOneOrFalse(someOne: { one?: boolean }): boolean {
    if ("one" in someOne) {
        return someOne.one; // error!  boolean | undefined        
    }
    if (typeof someOne.one !== "undefined") {
        return someOne.one; // okay
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

But, apparently, changing to `typeof someTest[prop] === "undefined"` doesn't work for your `getPropOrFalse()` function:

```
function badGetPropOrFalse(someTest: Partial<Test>, prop: keyof Test): boolean {
    if (typeof someTest[prop] !== "undefined") {
        return someTest[prop]; // still error! boolean | undefined
    }
    return false;
}
```

What gives?  That's the second thing:

The problem has to do with trying to type guard against an *indexed* property access (with brackets) when the property is not a single [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).  In your case since `prop` is a variable, and of the union type `"one" | "two"`, the compiler is unable (or unwilling) to perform control-flow analysis narrowing ([see microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530)).  I guess there was an [attempt](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10565) to address this, but it had a significant performance impact so it seems to have been abandoned (or at least delayed).  I'd expect some performance hit, since in order for this to work, the compiler would have to keep specific track of the type of "the variable `someTest` when indexed by the variable `prop`", which cannot be easily translated into narrowing just the type of `someTest`.  (After all, if I had two properties, `prop1` and `prop2` both of type `keyof Test`, and I checked `someTest[prop1]`, it would have no bearing on the type of `someTest[prop2]`, despite the fact that `prop1` and `prop2` are identical types according to the type system.)

The way to deal with this is to relieve the compiler of the burden of keeping track of variable-indexed-by-variable and just assign that to a new `const` variable in the first place, as mentioned in the other answer:

```
function getPropOrFalse(someTest: Partial<Test>, prop: keyof Test): boolean {
    const val = someTest[prop]; // boolean | undefined
    if (typeof val !== "undefined") {
        return val; // okay
    }
    return false;
}
```

And of course, once we start refactoring like this, we can go all the way:

```
function simplestGetPropOrFalse(someTest: Partial<Test>, prop: keyof Test): boolean {
    return someTest[prop] ?? false;
}
```

(which uses the newly added [nullish coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) operator)

---

Okay, hope that helps explain what's going on.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHID2IEAXMgEbHEA2EcIA3AUWAO7GU32Mt4AvnjwBzCGAAKUYgAcA8lABicOhggAKHCTKUAriAAmEGKAiHkggDTIARKQi2AlKzwwDCMMFLU4hgOIS0nKKKmqaGMQAthDoWJSScFBeqgA8cWAAfDayMrKUANYQAJ7EMGiYYE48tAxMuGyEwOUauXLIoMiRMRlODUQDyFASelAgXdGxlQDabbIAuszIAPTLyNAyUACE1LX8yAA+yAbGpmSGjZaXzcgaYMWyEGUTPTNz88hbALxfdicmZkMzn6g0IwzAo3G3SmWFmeUWKzWWGAdDo6ygmx2vDq4yO-zO5kuwgG4MhyHg4VYwjcHi8PnEYHkZFCqnUGmhTIouB0EAA-DU+PVBNVdoLxvgBjcNPYyLYOlDJpy+hLQUMRmMXhBOQA6BxLVbozGEbH7PFGAHnVXIInXFr3R7PDlkXVkT4-P7mglA5WXEnqhUxHV6xEkApwYo2v0QjUU9RUkQ0kCebzjBnBBTKVkRSYZBJJFJ0dKVbLIOaFErPXoCnEgwgIUhYZAAN1UyF+0IycLkCINJvqZtOgNtt3tT3KLbR31+tnxgOBKtBpI1E-1a2IYYjA2JRCX41jEHjieTPgwwCisgYWECUjyLPC7JzlTzyWAaQyJbLyCKpXKVdFNYXNVowDGEwC7BZkF5XlySzQ8gA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how TypeScript uses the `in` operator for type checking, but if you want a type guard for `undefined` you should use `typeof`:

```
const value = someTest[prop];
if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
  return value;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. You are certainly right, that I can do it that way, but I am particularly interested to learn, why typescript is not narrowing down the type of `someTest[prop]`, if I did a check before.